# Traffic Lights in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

please someone help me on how to use time in vb.net.I would like to make a traffic lights program in vb.net but am not yet sure where to start besides the interface.I want the lights to change within a give time.I have just started learning vb.net, about 2 weeks ago.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the timer function.  In short you can set it to execute code at an interveral you choose.  You can also change the interval. For example when turning the light green set the interval to 60 seconds, after the 60 seconds the 'tick' event is fired, and you can process code (in the tick routine) to turn the light yellow and set the interval to 15 seconds, and so forth.